# java synchronization with executor framework

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, threadpoolexecutor

What's wrong with this code?

```
public class SimpleThreadPool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);  
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {  
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);  
            executor.execute(worker);  
          }
        WorkerThread obj = new WorkerThread();
        System.out.println(obj.getCount());
        executor.shutdown();  
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {  
        }  
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");  
    }  
}

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {  
    private String command; 
    private volatile static int count;
    public WorkerThread(){
    }
    public WorkerThread(String s){  
        this.command=s;  
    }  

    @Override 
    public void run() {  
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                processCommand();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  

    private void processCommand() throws InterruptedException {
        count++;
        System.out.println("count " + count);
        //Thread.sleep(500);    
    }  

    @Override 
    public String toString(){  
        return this.command;  
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the result of count as 2000 and that too at end... What's wrong with my code??
How can I make sure that the count is always incremented in correct order??
When should I use volatile or synchronized block or both??

Comment: You're using `2000` in your loop instead of `20000`. You haven't told us what is wrong with your code, what the actual result of execution is and how it differs from what you want.

Comment: Assuming processCommand() is supposed to do something more significant than increment a counter the original design still has a major flaw after fixing the synchronization. The first thing that happens in run() is synchronization on a shared resource. That lock is not let go until all the work a Worker is supposed to do is finished which effectively eliminates any gains from parallelizing. The run method really should be redesigned to something like synchronize, get any shared data to do this task, release, do task, synchronize, update shared results, release.

Comment: so is there any way to achieve the final output as 2000 without synchronizing processCommand()

Comment: Yes, as I said alluded to in my last comment. You only synchronize on the parts that access shared resources. For example if processCommand() computes some number that then should be added to counter you only synchronize when reading/writing from counter because that is the only data set shared between threads. If your final result really is an int you might consider looking up [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are synchronizing on `this`.  But when you do this, you are having each `WorkerThread` lock itself, which is not productive.

The `processCommand` method is not atomic, so outputs will come out of order.  Also, the increment is not atomic either; it must read the value, increment the value, and store the value back into the variable.

Making `count` `volatile` only ensures that an updated value will be visible to other threads immediately after it's written, preventing an old value being read by another thread after it's been written.

If you synchronize on one object across all threads (`WorkerThread.class` will work here), then each `Thread` will update and print safely.

```
synchronized (WorkerThread.class) {
    processCommand();
}
```

If you synchronize properly as above, then `volatile` isn't necessary here, although it won't hurt anything; access to `count` is fully controlled.

**Note:** I included this before the question was edited to say `2000` instead of `20000`; it's no longer relevant.

Also, to get `20000`, you probably want 20000 tasks; they each increment the value only once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `synchronized (this)`, since that means that all your workers are synchronizing on different objects, namely themselves, which accomplishes nothing. You need them to synchronize on the same object.

One way of solving your problem is to instead synchronize on the class:

```
synchronized (this.getClass()) {
    processCommand();
}
```

Note also that there is no need to use both `synchronized` and `volatile`, the `synchronized` block assures that you will see an updated value for `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could make count an AtomicInteger, and use the getAndIncrement() on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class IncrementThread implements Runnable{
    private static volatile int count;
    private String name;
    public IncrementThread(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    public void run() {     
        synchronized (IncrementThread.class) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //count = count + 1;
            count++;
            System.out.println("count is : "+count);
        }       
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }   
}


import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestIncrementThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Runnable threadToRun = new IncrementThread("Increment");
        for(int i=0;i <2000; i++){
            executor.execute(threadToRun);          
        }       
        IncrementThread it = new IncrementThread("Increment");      
        executor.shutdown();    
        if(executor.isTerminated())
            System.out.println("Final count: "+it.getCount());
    }   
}


The above code will help you to achieve your goal.
```

Comment: Please comment on your code. The user has specifically asked: "what is wrong?".

Answer (score 0):

as @Keppil mentioned, you can not use `synchronized (this)` . because in this case every thread works on different object but as per your requirement you need to increment variable under same object. and this is what i found wrong with your code. please use `synchronized (WorkerThread.class)` to achieve result you want. in this way every thread will work in synchronized way only. and yes you can remove `volatile` keyword for your requirement.